# validation returns false, but element still passes. Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

Good Day,
So here is what I'm trying to do, I'm attempting to validate a username and confirm there is no other usernames in the database, and I think I'd found a solution. I believe I am returning false into the validator but the response still posts to the database.
If I need to provide more let me know

```
const userSchema = new Mongoose.Schema (
    {
        playerName : {
            type: String, 
            required: (true, "No Name Specified"),
            validate: {
                validator(val) {
                value = true
                User.findOne( { "playerName" : val}, function(err, result) {
                 if (result != null) {
                    value = false 
                    
                 }
                                   
                })
                return value
            
            },
                   
                
                
                message: "playerName already Exsits"
            }
        },
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your validator is not waiting to the response and is reaching `return value` (which is true) before the callback `value = false`.

So you need an `async` validator like this:

```
const userSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
            playerName: {
                type: String,
                required: (true, "No Name Specified"),
                validate: {
                    async validator(val) {
                        const result = await User.findOne({
                            "playerName": val
                        })
                        return result == null ? true : false
                    },
                    message: "playerName already Exsits"
                }
            },
```